# How can i get the same ajax result using WP REST API instead of admin-ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have been told that admin-ajax is outdated now and it's better to use REST API instead but I was wondering how can I get the same result of this code which generates a button with a link based on some variables and custom fields using REST API?

also, someone told me that this code is not secure because I'm using HTML response instead of data in ajax but I'm wondering how to use data for this code?

I apologize but i'm still very new to coding

```
    <?php   

  add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'simple_amz_link_ajax', 10);


function simple_amz_link_ajax() {   
?>
<script>

jQuery(document).ready(function(){

             jQuery.ajax({
                url: "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>",
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                         action: 'getmyfunctionform1',
                         postId: <?php echo get_post()->ID; ?>
                },
                dataType: 'html',
                success: function(response) {

                jQuery("#buy_amz_btn_wrap").html(response);

                }

        }); 
    });
</script> 
<!-- end Ajax call to getmyfunctionform1 smc 11-22-2013 -->

<div id="buy_amz_btn_wrap"> Loading ... </div>

<?php
}

// Amazon Simple Button Function

add_action('wp_ajax_getmyfunctionform1', 'myfunctionform1');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_getmyfunctionform1', 'myfunctionform1');

function myfunctionform1() { 
    $postId = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'postId', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT );
    $country_code = $_SERVER ["HTTP_CF_IPCOUNTRY"];
    $de_asin = get_post_meta( $postId, "wccaf_de_asin", true );
    $uk_asin = get_post_meta( $postId, "wccaf_uk_asin", true );    

    $not_avilable_country = '<div id="amz_not_avilable" class="amz_not_avilable">This product is not avilable in your country yet</div>';


//////////////////////////////////////////////


if ($country_code=="DE" or $country_code=="DE") {
    $amazon_domain = 'https://www.amazon.de';
    $associate_id = 'bonstato-21';
    $asin = $de_asin;
}

else if ($country_code=="GB" && $uk_asin!=="") {
    $amazon_domain = 'https://www.amazon.co.uk';
    $associate_id = 'bonmedico-21';
    $asin = $uk_asin;
}

///////////////////

global $post;
        $product = wc_get_product( $postId );
        $type = $product->get_type();
        if( $type == 'simple' && $asin!="" ){   

                // Amazon Link For Mobile       
                ?>
                <script>
                    function amzGo(){
                        window.location='<?php echo $amazon_domain ?>/dp/<?php echo $asin ?>/?tag=<?php echo $associate_id ?>';
                }
                </script>
                <?php


        ?>
            <div class="buy_amz_btn_wrap" >  
                <button type="button" id="buy_amz_btn" class="buy_amz_btn" onclick="amzGo();"><i class="fa fa-amazon fa-amz"></i><?php echo $amz_btn_title ?></button>                           
            </div>
        <?php
        }

        else if( $type == 'simple' && $asin=="" ){   
            echo $not_avilable_country;
}


die(); 

} 
?>
```

Comment: 1. You can create [custom endpoints](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/) for the API. 2. You can use an output buffer for your html and echo it using `json_encode()`.

Comment: @Michael Thanks Michael for your reply, Could you please give me a simple example showing how to do that, it would be great if that example has "get_post()->ID" used on it. Would really appreciate that

Comment: Why don't you give it a try and post it in your updated question? All the infos should be there in the WP documentation.

Comment: 'admin-ajax is outdated now and it's better to use REST API' - can you please provide a reference for this. REST - Representational State Transfer - really is designed for synchronizing objects between the backend server and the front end client. Although, it can be made to do almost anything through custom endpoints it is unnatural (and unnecessarily difficult) to do things that are not related to synchronizing objects.